# Variable empty, while after calculation shouldnt be empty. How to do this correctly?

Tags: php, variables, time

imagine I want to calculate speed of loading, 
and then echo that calculated value.
However... I wish to echo that value not at the end of the page, on the bottom of html, but somewhere in the middle of the html:

```
    $s = microtime(true); 

<html><head>...</head><body>   
     echo $laadtijd . " seconds";   //echo value, after calculation completed
</body></html>  

    $e = microtime(true);  
    $laadtijd = round($e - $s, 3);  //fill in the value
```

However, now the page shows an empty value for $laadtijd, while it has been calculated! How to solve this?

Comment: Is `$laadtijd` calculated before that `echo`?

Comment: calculated after the echo. and after that should give the value to the middle of the page sothat it can show the value. is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by doing:

```
<?php

    // Start time
    $s = microtime(true);

    // Holds the output buffer
    ob_start(); 
    echo '
         <html>
              <head>...</head>
              <body>....
              TIME_CALCULATED seconds.
              </body>
        </html>'; // TIME_CALCULATED will be our flag

    // Get the output
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    // End time
    $e = microtime(true);
    $laadtijd = round($e - $s, 3);

    // Echo the output
    echo str_replace('TIME_CALCULATED', $laadtijd, $output);

?>
```

This simply holds the output buffer with all the content and replaces our flag `TIME_CALCULATED` in the buffer with the time.

For more info read [Output Control Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) on PHP's Manual.

Answer (score 0):

HOW CAN YOU CALCULATE LOAD SPEED OF ENTIRE PAGE UNLESS IT HAS BEEN LOADED? YOU calculated $laadtijd somewhere towards the end then how can you echo it in middle???
using microtime its impossible to be precise with time taken to load page.(i am not sure though)

```
<?php
$s = microtime(true);
?>
<html><head>...</head>
<body>
show you entire page
<?php
$e = microtime(true);
$laadtijd = round($e - $s, 3);//calculate first then echo
echo $laadtijd . " seconds";
?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I will rephrase my question better. Thanks for critique +1